# MacOS shared library path

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, ld

I have a C++ application that depends on several `.dylib`; Amongst them, `libproj` and `PythonQt`.

I pre-built these libs in separate directories.

2 (related) questions :

- The executable finds the full path of the `libproj.dylib`, although it's not in the path, not in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not in QtCreator's configuration. How ?
- The executable does NOT find PythonQt, although it's linked exactly the same way. I have to manually add the right path in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Why ?

It's probably related to the fact that there is a `.la` and a `.dylib` for libproj, but only a `.dylib` for PythonQt; but I'm not sure and I don't understand the relation.

Sample output of otool :

```
/Users/arnaud/Projects/myprojectname/external/proj-4.8.0/bin_mac64_gcc421_release/lib/libproj.0.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    ( so it finds libproj correctly, even in another directory )

libPythonQt.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    (... but not libPythonQt, which is in a similar directory )

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 697.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```